# Shortest path through a node

Tags: neo4j, cypher

How to get the shtortest path between two nodes, where the path is going through a specific node. This is what I've got so far:

```
MATCH (a:User { username:"User1" }),(b:User { username:"User2" }),(c:User { username:"User3" }),
  p = allShortestPaths((a)-[*]-(b))
RETURN p
```

I want a result in which the path goes through User3 (c).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find each leg separately:

```
MATCH (a:User {username:"User1"}),(b:User {username:"User2"}),(c:User {username:"User3"}),
  p = allShortestPaths((a)-[*]-(c)), q = allShortestPaths((c)-[*]-(b))
RETURN p, q
```

Be aware, though, that if you have very long paths, or cycles, this query can take a long time or never finish. You should consider putting an upper bound on the path lengths, e.g.:

```
MATCH (a:User {username:"User1"}),(b:User {username:"User2"}),(c:User {username:"User3"}),
  p = allShortestPaths((a)-[*..10]-(c)), q = allShortestPaths((c)-[*..10]-(b))
RETURN p, q
```

Comment: This works for. Great answer and explanation, thank you!